# How to print the header and footer of the HTML page

Tags: html, css, media

I tried to add the header and footer in each page for the HTML print. I write the below code

```css
@page {
  @top-left {
    content: "this is the page header";
  }
}

@page: right {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) "page";
  }
}
```

It is not working. I think the @bottom-right, @bottom-left etc features are removed in recent CSS update. These elements not showing anything. I already tried the following code

```html
<style>
@media print {
  .page-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  .page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
</style>
<section class='print-me'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div col='6'>..... dynamically generated text, graphs and images about 30 pages long which are difficult to handle manually ....</div>
   </div>
</section>

 <!-- I need this page header and footer in every page -->
 <h5 class="page-header">..... copyright and logo ...../h5>
 <h5 class="page-footer">..... page number: .....</h5>
 <!-- I want to generate page number dynamically -->
```

Since I have around 30 pages of HTML content having very long paragraphs which are generated dynamically, if I tried the second method, It will overlap with header and footer.

**edit**: [I found this article on medium](https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a). This helps me to generate the header and footer somehow. But this technique also breaks my tables inside the report. There is also missing the page number generation part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some tricks pulled from a project I've not yet published for generating Resumes...

```
/* Thanks be to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646835/print-repeating-page-headers-in-chrome/25880258#25880258
   And may allow for repeated headers only in print preview
 */
div[class*="resume-section-experience-"] {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}
div[class*="resume-section-experience-"] > div {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Add further section repetition hiding here */
.resume-section-experience-professional ~ .resume-section-experience-professional > div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -3em; // inverse of header height
}
.resume-section-experience-volunteer ~ .resume-section-experience-volunteer > div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -3em; /* inverse of header height */
}

.resume-headings {
  height: 3em;
}
div[class*="resume-section-experience-"] > div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/**
 * Attempt to keep section headings from displaying at the bottom of pages
 * and discourage page brakes within various content blocks.
 */
@media print {
  h2, h3, h4, ul, .professional-experience {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }

  pre, blockquote, ul, div[class*="-training"], div[class*="-requirements"], div[class*="-experience"], div[class*="-skills"], div[class*="resume-section-experience-"] {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

... you'll have to adjust element names/classes that are targeted, and perhaps fiddle with spacing between paragraphs, but the above code is what functions similar requirements.

All that said, if you know that paragraphs are going to be broken between pages at some-point, it may instead be better to shrink the available height of that container such that there is space for fixed positioned headers and footers.

If ya edit your question to include some of the markup (and notify me), I'll try to swing through again with edits to this answer that may better address your specific use cases.

> One additional note on the above CSS; for my use-cases I found that repeating header/footer data and then selectively hiding'em when not at the top/bottom of the page was easier to format between web and print views.

---

> > @dhiraj
> >     ... The main problem is how to generate page number

If page numbers be the main concern then it *should* be possible to utilize <s>`display: table`, `display: table-footer-group`, and</s> CSS's counter tricks...

### `print.css`

```
/**
 * print modifications **must** be within a style sheet
 */
@media print {
  /*
   * Note, forced page breaks are only for testing when content is insufficient
   */
  .page_content__print_break {
    page-break-after: always;
    break-after: always;
  }

  footer.footer_content {
    visibility: show;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);

    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  footer.footer_content::after {
    counter-increment: page_number;
    content: "Page:" counter(page_number);
  }
}
```

### `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Table based CSS footer example</title>

    <style media="screen">
      footer.footer_content,
      .page_content__print_break {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css">
  </head>


  <body>
    <section class="page_content">
      <div class="page_content__row">
        <p>This is where page content should be placed</p>
        <p>
          Thanks be to:
           <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939">
             Print page numbers on pages when printing html
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <!--
        Note, following element is only for this example and should
        be removed for the use-case of this posted quesiton.
      -->
      <div class="page_content__print_break"></div>

      <div class="page_content__row">
        <p>
          More example content to perhaps force a second page to be printed...
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>

    </section>


    <footer class="footer_content" role="contentinfo"></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Side note, upon reviewing the internally linked to Q&A above I found that `@page` that you're using within the current question may not be feature fully supported by CSS, to get more *fanciness* requires [PagedJS](https://www.pagedjs.org/)
>
> And perhaps check the official CSS documentation on supported [`@page`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html) features.

... however, after some testing it seems as though browser support has changed in recent years; both Firefox and Chrome seem to not do `counter` stuff when printing, and `page-break-*` has changed to `break-*` though that property now seems to be ignored by both browsers :-|

> Edit; the comment by [@contm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050986/2632107) stated that linking style sheets vs. style within `head` element may produce different results X-\

In fact after reviewing [Mozilla's developer documentation on `break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after) compatibility chart, this feature is supported by Internet Exporter

If I find anything that resolves these issues I'll be certain to pop by again with another edit to this answer.

---

Updates;

According to CSS spec. for [`@page`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#at-page-rule) it's currently a WIP (draft or Work In Progress) so as of 2020 no vendors can be expected to implement.

Footers that are *`fixed`* instead of repeated are only calculated once and after all increments have finished; an example that'll report *`Page: 2`* on every page because there are two *`page_content__row`s*...

### `print.css`

```
@media print {
  :root {
    counter-reset: page_count;
  }

  .page_content__row {
    counter-increment: page_count;
  }

  .page_content__print_break {
    page-break-after: always;
    break-after: always;
  }

  footer.footer_content {
    visibility: show;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);

    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  footer.footer_content::after {
    content: "Page: " counter(page_count);
  }
}
```

... aside from third-party libraries the only other option that I can think of for customizing footer information is calculating page breaks at the time that your content is dynamically generated, and then *injecting* footer element(s) where needed. This of course has the huge draw-back in that client font/zoom settings will either mess-up footer customizations or have to be ignored, which if ya go that route it may be simpler to instead generate the PDF document server-side and provide a download link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already updated my question. Any help?? The main problem is how to generate page number.

Comment: You're most certainly welcome @dhiraj! With the clearer exceptions I've made some additions to this answer that may bring success closer. Feel free to hit me up again if not, and I'll be sure to spend a bit more time researching solutions with ya.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I figure out everything except one thing, i.e. `page number`. Since the contents are dynamic, I can not set  `page_content__print_break` to every page and count the page number. Also, my generated report having size 15-30 pages based on user selection. I tried with `pagedjs` and it still has lots of CSS errors. Do you have any good idea about the page number?

Comment: `page_content__print_break` stuff can be removed for your use-case; it's in the example code to ensure there are multiple pages within print previews. I'm ignorant on `PagedJS` and it's included only because others had stated that it responds to `@page` properties, as does `PrinceXML`; if the internet is to be believed... While I _pick_ at this on my end, section 4 of the CSS spec. on [auto-numbering](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#auto-numbering) may be worth review; specifically scoping limitations.

Comment: Also the [`@page`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#at-page-rule) spec. states that property is a **draft** (Work in Progress) and because of that it should not be used/cited. Or in other words, `@page` is a _dream_ of future features and at this time we cannot expect any vendors to implement it... And after some more testing it looks like pure CSS will **not** be able to properly increment page counts without also repeating footer elements, because a fixed footer is only counted/incremented once. But if content generation is able to calculate and add hidden footers that might still work.

Comment: Ya, that's right. But I am unable to add the hidden footer since the report is generated dynamically. Still looking for the page number.